# How do I define another temporary variable and fetch into it?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

Here is My code;-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetDeails
    (c_name    VARCHAR2,
    calories   NUMBER)


DECLARE
    CURSOR cur IS SELECT CATEGORY.Name FROM  CATEGORY INNER JOIN  FILLING ON CATEGORY.CategoryID = FILLING.CategoryID
    WHERE c_name=FillING.Name AND calories=GramCalories;
    fil cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

    OPEN cur;
    LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO fil;
    EXIT WHEN (cur%NOTFOUND);
    IF fil%NOTFOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('NotFound');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(fil.c_name, fil.calories);
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END GetDetails;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `PROCEDURE` statement is good, but having some little issues, such as :

- Convert the name `GetDeails` to `GetDetails` in order to have the
  matching name with the one given at the end after the last `END`
  keyword. Indeed, using the `PROCEDURE`'s name twice is redundant, so,
  not needed.
- There should be `IS` or `AS` keyword just after IN parameters' list, and the keyword `DECLARE` should be removed.
- `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE` should be converted to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`,
  and two matching columns( `Name` and `GramCalories` ) should be provided in the `CURSOR`'s `SELECT` list.
- cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor `FIL` but to `CUR`

  ```
  SQL> SET serveroutput ON
  SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetDetails( c_name VARCHAR2, calories NUMBER ) IS

      CURSOR cur IS 
      SELECT f.Name, c.GramCalories 
        FROM CATEGORY c
        JOIN FILLING f
          ON f.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
       WHERE c_name=f.Name 
         AND calories=GramCalories;     

      fil cur%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN

      OPEN cur;
      LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO fil;
      EXIT WHEN (cur%NOTFOUND);
      IF cur%NOTFOUND THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NotFound');
      ELSE
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fil.name, fil.calories);
      END IF;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur;
  END;
  /
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Barbaros solves most of your issue but can be further refined.

The IF statement within the loop is completely unnecessary as it will never return True when executed. If it were true the exit
statement preceding it would have exited the loop; thus no message. This is redundant; making a test where the result is already known.  You could reverse the order and put the exit after the IF...END IF. But then the 'not found' message would always be produced. You can use cur%rowcount after the loop to generate the message correctly.  
  
The dbms_output_put_line(fil.name,fil.calories) has 2 errors.

- variable fil.calories does not exist. GramCalories was not selected in your original (as pointed out) nor aliased in the revision. So is not part of the cursor and thus not part of the
  cursor row type.
- It requires a single string parameter, as is there are 2 parameters.

Taking these into account we get:

```
create or replace procedure getdetails( c_name varchar2, calories number ) is

    cursor cur is 
    select f.name, c.gramcalories 
      from category c
      join filling f
        on f.categoryid = c.categoryid
     where c_name=f.name 
       and calories=gramcalories;
    fil cur%rowtype;

 begin
    open cur;

    loop
    fetch cur into fil;
    exit when (cur%notfound);
        dbms_output.put_line(fil.name || ' ' || fil..gramcalories);
    end loop;

    if cur%rowcount = 0 then 
          dbms_output.put_line('Not Found');
    end if;

    close cur;
end getdetails;
/
```

As a ***matter of style***:

- Avoid the CamelCase naming convention. **Oracle always folds object names to uppercase**. Thus it just makes Oracle generated references difficult to read. Instead use words separated by Underscore (_).
- Unlike Barbaros I do not consider using the procedure (function,
  package, ...) name on the terminating end as redundant but more as a
  closure as much as an 'end if'. Yes it is syntactically optional, but
  optional is not the same a redundant. I always exercise that option.
  So developed your style (subject to institutional/customer mandated
  standards), but be consistent with it.